# Limiting permissions to the author not working in Firestore rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am attempting to move my Firebase rules from testing where every user could read and write every document to one where only the author can update or delete documents they create.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null;
      allow update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.author_uid;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

This set of rules is resulting in a 'Missing or insufficient permissions" error at Firebase init and if I attempt to delete a document. If I go with my original rules then everything works.

```
allow read, create: if request.auth != null
```

I do a standard firebase.initializeApp (but dont want to publish my keys here - lets just say the same initialize works with the basic rules and on three other firebase projects I have). The delete call is as follows and works with the simpler rule set as well but not the tighter rules above:

```
const decrement = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1);
firestore.collection('story').doc(storyid).delete().then(function() {
    firestore.collection('users').doc(getUserID()).update({
        saves: decrement 
    });
})
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  Just seeing the rules alone isn't helpful - code and rules should always match, and we need to see that.  We should also be able to reproduce the situation fully using what you provide.

Comment: Well since Firebase does not tell you where the code is failing its very hard to pinpoint ... and I cannot post the init and every call to firestore read, write and update. I'll add a bit to the question but a first level answer would be 'is my rule set correct for what i want to do which is only allow updates, deletes and creates by the person logged in on their own data'?

Comment: Firebase doesn't control Stack Overflow, and I'm seeing that two people who are not Firebase staff have voted to close the question, likely because your update didn't come in time.  By Stack Overflow conventions, it got closed simply because enough people have agreed that it's off-topic, which happens all the time.   I suggest reading the links to understand how to ask a better question, and post it again with your revisions.

Comment: As a small piece of advice that I hope you find helpful in the future - your first response here (which you removed) said that you didn't think you should have to show the matching code sample that I requested in my first comment.  That would be enough for potential reviewers of the question to close it as "off-topic" seeking debugging help without enough info.  Now that you've taken the time to add the requested information, it seems that the question has been re-opened.  The moderation process is intended to help people ask better questions.  Sorry you had a bad experience with that.

Comment: Apologies that I put that first comment in before expanding the code samples as much as possible. Its on me. Answer below should help people and give them even better options when faced with the rules question i had. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(thank to Sam Stern on the FB team for guidance)

First, there was a mistake in the rules description. While request.auth.uid is defined by firebase the resource.data.author_id needs to be defined by the developer on each of their documents. In this case the 'story' document contains a 'creator' property that is the userid of the owner. So the correct variable would be resource.data.creator in the above rules.

In addition its possible to define the documentid as the userid, as is often the case when you are creating a 'user' object for each account in your firebase app. In this case the userId is the same as the documentId so the following rule would control update permissions that only allow the owner of that document to change it.

```
 match /users/{userId} {
   // In this scope the "userId" variable is equal to the documentId because of the wildcard declaration {userId}
   allow update: if request.auth.uid == userId;
 }
```